# Flutter ios mobile web browser is always Safari

Tags: ios, flutter, google-chrome, web, safari

I'm trying to get the correct browser name in Flutter app launched in ios mobile browser. I'm getting weird output calling multiple methods, being in Chrome actually:

```
var broswer = Browser().browserAgent;
var deviceInfo = DeviceInfo();


WebBrowserInfo? info = deviceInfo.WebBrowserInfo;

       {
          info?.platform: iPhone,
          info?.appName: Netscape,
          info?.userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_5 like Mac OS X)...Safari/604.1,
          info?.appCodeName: Mozilla,
          Browser().browserAgent: BrowserAgent.Safari,
          Browser().version: Unknown version,
        }
```

Left is call, right is output.

Any ideas?